# textField does not show in the alertView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uialertview, ios7.1

Here is my code:

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 30)];
[textField setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

[theAlert addSubview:textField];

[theAlert show];
[textField release];
[theAlert release];
```

There is no textFiled in alertView, only a title "Alert" and a button "OK"

Comment: you might have no access to the `UIAlertView` instance's subviews via `–addSubview:` method. you may need to take a look on the `alertViewStyle` property instead to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Are you using ios 7 ?

Comment: As of iOS7 you can't add views to UIAlertView

Comment: Why are you releasing both theAlert and textField directly after showing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your background color is clear so It's not showing

```
 [textField setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];.
```

and also show default text field

```
theAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

//or for username and password 
  theAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

//   or for   password
 theAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
```

Try this

Comment: In all honesty I'm not sure this is correct ever as you are telling them to just change the UIColor to red.

Comment: Yeah but your just telling him to change to red doesn't solve the problem of his code being wrong because of `[theAlert addSubview:textField];`

Answer (score 1):

I will refer you the Apple Documentation in regards to [`UIAlertView` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). Specifically

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified

So what this means is you can't add subviews to an instance of `UIAlertView` the recent `UIAlertView` still has the `addSubview:` method is because `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `UIView` which has this method, but as of iOS7 the method `addSubview:` for `UIAlertView` no longer calls the super method on `UIView` it just does nothing.

So basically what you are after is not possible.

There are however `alertViewStyle`s that you can use like `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` which will add a single `UITextField` to the `UIAlertView` which you can then access using the method `textFieldAtIndex:`. However please be aware that you can't really do anything with this again because it is part of the `UIAlertView`s hierarchy so again it is made to be used as is.

Messing with the `UIAlertView` hierarchy will get your app rejected from the Apple Review process under

> **2.5** - Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default alertView with textfield.For that you need to set the alertViewStyle

[message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

Here message is object of alertView.

You can get the textfield value using the delegate method as shown below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];

        NSLog(@"Username: %@\nPassword: %@", username.text, password.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can set `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;`

This will add a text field for you. You can access it in the
 `UIAlertView` delegate callback by using

`UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score -4):

If your using ios 7 then add below code to your set of code

```
 theAlert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

Full code

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 30)];
[textField setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
theAlert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[theAlert show];
```

Comment: Why do you still call `addSubview:` this goes against the Apple Documentation and since it doesn't actually do anything as of iOS7 it will not add a `UITextField` to the `UIAlertView` -1

Comment: @Sato And it is wrong, read the apple documentation supplied in my answer. Anything that calls `addSubview:` on an instance of `UIAlertView` is an incorrect answer. Just because it works doesn't mean it is correct. Notice all the -1 this answer is getting because it is wrong